# Validation form input val by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want check all input for activate my button but i have try the multiple code and don't work.

```
$(('#my_name') && ('#username') && ...).bind('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val())
    {
        $('.ouvrir-etape3').removeClass('gray');
        $('.ouvrir-etape3').slideDown(300); 
    }
    else
    {
        alert ('check the form');
    }
});

<form action="...">

  <div class="1">
    <input id="my_name">
    <input id="username">
  </div>

  <div class="ouvrir-etape3 gray">Open</div>
  <div style="display:none">...</div>

</form>
```

I want check all input by id. This code check the last input #username i don't why.

Comment: provide html so i will understand what you want.

Comment: Please add some more information like in which language you are using..

Comment: I have created a form  and i want check the input if not empty with jQuery  for diplay the button "Open"

Comment: I doubt you can apply multiple selectors with &&.

Comment: @Mike See my answer...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. By tagging your question with the language being used, you improve the likelihood of it being seen by someone with the expertise to answer it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written wrong syntax for bind event. Just replace with below code. it will work.

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Document</title>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>


    <form action="...">

    <div class="1">
      <input id="my_name">
      <input id="username">
    </div>

    <div class="ouvrir-etape3 gray">Open</div>
    <div style="display:none">...</div>

    </form>

    <script>
        $('#my_name,#username').bind('blur', function() {
          if ($('#my_name').val() && $('#username').val()){ $('.ouvrir-etape3').removeClass('gray');
            $('.ouvrir-etape3').slideDown(300); 
          }
          else
          {
            $('.ouvrir-etape3').addClass('gray');
            alert ('check the form');
          }
        });
    </script>  

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: @mike Please tick mark my answer if it is helpful to you. Thanks

Comment: I have tried same code but the problem is the only first input is checked. I want check all input for display the button

Comment: yes this will work for both the input fields. when ever you blur from particular input field it will check that particular field. If you need other then this let me know.

Comment: When i try this code , i click in the last input "just do it" and i write (the first is empty. after i click in out the button class gray is remove. i want write in two input for remove gray class. i go in jsfiddle for you look